# AFNetworking receiving a status code that has not send by server

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have a basic php script code that  receives JSON POST and sends back a http status code.

PHP successfully receives JSON and sends http 200 status code but somehow AFNetworking gets `Expected status code in (200-299), got 500`, in php script I define a 500 statuscode but I never use/send that status code, I have been looking to php script over and over again no it sends correct code `200` but AFNetworking receives it as `500`

PHP:

```
//send delete request here
    $query ="DELETE FROM OWN_EVENTS WHERE  event_id IN ('$names')";
    $result = $sql->query($query);
    //printf("$query: %s\n", $query);
    //var_dump($query);
    //printf("\n");     
    if (!$result) {
        //var_dump($result);
        //printf("\n");
        //printf("Query failed: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        sendResponse(417, json_encode("Query failed"));

    exit;
    }

    sendResponse(200, json_encode("Event Deleted"));
```

IOS

```
NSError* error;
    NSMutableDictionary *nameElements = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [nameElements setObject:saveArray forKey:@"event_id"];

    NSData *result =[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:nameElements options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *displayJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"saveArray result %@",displayJson);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:server];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    // don't forget to set parameterEncoding!
    httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:deleteEventInDatabase parameters:nil];
    [request setHTTPBody:[displayJson  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request addValue:@"ASIHTTPRequest" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSLog(@"request %@",request);
    [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:nil failure:nil];
    operation.JSONReadingOptions = NSJSONReadingAllowFragments;
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
        // Print the response body in text
        if (operation.response.statusCode == 200) {
            NSLog(@"Events Sucessfully Deleted");

        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        if (operation.response.statusCode == 500) {
            NSLog(@"Internal Server Error");
            //remove this when u fix it

        }
 }];

    [operation start];
```

ERROR:

```
Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 500" UserInfo=0x11c8c9d0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion="Event Deleted", AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest http://host.php>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://host.php, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 500, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xa9aba80>
```

As you can see in error it says `NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion="Event Deleted"` so php really sends `200`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there anything in the PHP/server logs about the response?

Comment: Also, have you been able to test the request in the browser?  I can't find `sendResponse` in the [PHP docs](http://us3.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=sendResponse&lang=en&scope=quickref).

Comment: I have tested it with curl it returns "Event Deleted" `curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"event_id":["420"]}'  http://host.php`

Comment: `-v` should also display the response header.  I assume you're getting back `< HTTP/1.1 200 OK` as the first response line.  Can you share the full curl output?

Answer (score 2):

500 is the HTTP status code for an internal server error. The problem is entirely in how your php script is responding to the request.

Comment: Gonna try to correct my php script then, and post my solution when I have one